# Why is logistic regression in R creating multiple coefficients for one variable?

Tags: r, logistic

Thank you so much for your input to my question. My variable is HPtsLag and is continuous (although integers, and <=18 - perhaps this could be the issue?).  Anyway, here is my code and output. Hopefully this explains it better.

```
> mylog = glm(cbind(HW,NotHW) ~ HPtsLag, data = g, family = binomial)
> summary (mylog)
```

Call:

```
> glm(formula = cbind(HW, NotHW) ~ HPtsLag, family = binomial, data = g)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.5898  -1.0787  -0.9431   1.2142   1.6259  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  -1.0116     0.3371  -3.001  0.00269 ** 
HPtsLag1      0.3998     0.4023   0.994  0.32031    
HPtsLag10     0.9255     0.3527   2.624  0.00869 ** 
HPtsLag11     0.9694     0.3613   2.683  0.00729 ** 
HPtsLag12     1.0722     0.3659   2.931  0.00338 ** 
HPtsLag13     1.5224     0.3652   4.168 3.07e-05 ***
HPtsLag14     1.7693     0.4032   4.388 1.15e-05 ***
HPtsLag15     1.2658     0.4004   3.161  0.00157 ** 
HPtsLag16     1.8348     0.3919   4.681 2.85e-06 ***
HPtsLag18     1.9432     0.4700   4.135 3.55e-05 ***
HPtsLag2      0.4318     0.3883   1.112  0.26615    
HPtsLag3      0.7807     0.3700   2.110  0.03488 *  
HPtsLag4      0.5873     0.3565   1.648  0.09944 .  
HPtsLag5      0.6881     0.3544   1.942  0.05219 .  
HPtsLag6      0.6862     0.3545   1.936  0.05292 .  
HPtsLag7      0.6956     0.3508   1.983  0.04739 *  
HPtsLag8      0.7749     0.3532   2.194  0.02824 *  
HPtsLag9      0.9588     0.3541   2.708  0.00677 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 5432.7  on 3929  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 5314.6  on 3912  degrees of freedom
AIC: 5350.6

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

**Why is this happening?**

Comment: Is your variable VAR continuous or categorical?

Comment: Could you provide your R code with the R function you use? As such your question does not make sense.

Comment: The extra terns could be coefficients of the higher order terms $x^2$, $x^3$, $x^4$.

Answer (score 7):

The object `var` is stored as a factor - or perhaps as a character. You can check this by examining `str(var)` - to get the structure of {var}. By what you write, I guess you want to store {var} as a numeric variable; in this case create `var2 <- as.numeric(var)` and use `var2` in your regression.

The problem also often occurs when the data hasn't been read in correctly, from wherever it's been stored. You could check your use of `read.table()`, or similar commands to read in data.

Comment: OK - i see what's happening (at least I think I do.) It's treating this as a categorical variable instead of continuous. How do I tell R they're continuous? (I'm a new user so sorry for novice questions!)

Comment: R treats variables stored as numeric (like `var2` above) as continuous. So, using `var2` should give you what you want - check the output has just one coefficient.